# duplicating nodes of a single list in c

Tags: c, list, pointers, malloc, nodes

i have a single list non-circular without sentinel and i want to duplicate every node of it. For example, i have 7,5,12,16 and i want to have : 7,7,5,5,12,12,16,16 but i can't create it.Below is my function code for duplicate the nodes(other parts of the program are correct).

```
    int duplicate_list(listT *list_head) {
    listT *current, *new_node;

    for(current = list_head; current != NULL; current = current->next,counter++) {
            new_node = (listT *)malloc(sizeof(listT));
            if(new_node == NULL) {
                printf("problem in new_node\n");
                free(new_node);
                exit(-1);
            }

            new_node->data = current->data;
            new_node->next = current;
    }
    return(1);
 }
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is `listT`?

Comment: [Don't cast `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Don't print error messages to `stdout`.

Comment: `free(NULL);` is a no-op.

Comment: `counter` is undeclared.

Comment: Why return a value at all if the only possible return value is `1`?

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not inserting duplicate `new_node` in the list, you are just creating the new nodes in loop. Consider below example for your reference.

```
    int duplicate_list(listT *list_head) {
    listT *current, *new_node;

    for(current = list_head; current != NULL; current = current->next,counter++) {
            new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
            if(new_node == NULL) {
                perror("problem in new_node");
                exit(1);
            }

            new_node->data = current->data;
            new_node->next = current->next;
            current->next = new_node;
            current = new_node;
    }
    return(1);
 }
```

Comment: Without any explanation in English, your answer has no interest to a newbie

Comment: Most of my comments also apply to your code. In addition: `perror` automatically adds a `:`, a space, and an error reason to the provided message, so having a `\n` in there probably ends up looking ugly.